# Root document index.html hosted on CloudFront stuck in local browser cache

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control, etag, http-caching

I have a CloudFront distribution with a single origin and behaviour mapped to an S3 bucket. This has been working fine for years.
Today I replaced the `index.html` file and invalidated the distribution for paths `/*`.
After this, fetching https://my.webpage.com/index.html in Chrome gets me the new page, but fetching https://my.webpage.com gets me the old page, but if I do "view source" in Chrome, I see the source of my *new* `index.html`. What is going on!?

If I cURL or use Postman to get the file, I get the new version, and I can verify that `cache-control` is set to `nocache;max-age=0` and the ETag was changed when the version was replaced.

However when I go to Chrome and open the URL I still see the old file, with `Last-Modified` set to 4 weeks ago, and the network tab indicates that the file was returned from the local disk cache.

I tried setting the max TTL to 1 in CloudFront and invalidate again, but with no luck. Whatever I do, it seems Chrome does not even try to see if the file has been changed on the server.
What could be causing this? I've rolled out a new version of my web page and I don't want to ask users to do a hard reload!?

Comment: Can you help us by trying to access the same endpoint from a browser that didn't accessed it before? If you clear Chrome's cache for static files, what do you see? If you start seeing the newer page, can you run another invalidate command and share you results with us? Can you also check if your CloudFront distribution is connected to any Lambda@Edge or offers custom headers configuration that messes with the cache related headers?

Comment: I think, when you do a full page refresh or type anything in URL and hit enter, browser sends `Cache-control: max-age=0` in the request. This never happened with me that a website's root page is cached by browser and request never reaching to the server.